when compiling with gcc, I have to be in the home directory for gcc to find the file
Is there a work around for this. The Home directory will get cluttered fairly quick or is this a bug in gcc. I'm using ubuntu24 and gcc 13.2.

What do you mean "in the home directory for gcc to find the file"? Does it not work if you try to compile something in a directory other than the home directory (assuming the directory you're in contains the source file)? Or do you mean "in the same directory for gcc to find the file", reagrdless of whether that is the home directory or a different directory?

This is not a GCC bug.
You have to either change the terminal directory to the directory of the source code for GCC (or any other program) to find the file if you just give the file name, or you can give the full path to the file.
So either:
cd /path/to/directory/of/source

Then run
gcc source.c -o output.bin

Alternatively, give the full path to GCC
gcc /path/to/source.c -o /path/to/output.bin


Example: Suppose I have the file code.c in Downloads/my-source in the home folder. Then, I have to run the commands
cd Downloads/my-source
gcc code.c -o output-program-name


@terdon Thanks for pointing out. I have updated the answer. I have a feeling that OP either did not provide the full path or did not change to the correct directory

Thanks, I made another edit to make it clearer, I hope you don't mind.

if i cd to the source directory then gcc will not find the file. I have to either move the .c file to the home directory. I'll just make a bash edit with the full path

@BillInIowa How did you install gcc?

Installed it thru visual code for linux. In visual code, all is ok. Its just the terminal that i have to give gcc a path or put the source file in the home directory.
